# Как открыть файл .lib в Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

При попытке открыть файл vcompd.lib появляется сообщение:

> Нет редактора для "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcompd.lib"
>   Убедитесь, что установлено приложение для типа файлов .lib

Какое приложение необходимо установить, чтобы открывать и читать файлы .lib?

Comment: а что вы хотели посмотреть в скомпилированном бинарнике?

Comment: IDA Pro, например, может работать с *.lib. Но кажется вы хотите чего-то странного...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.lib файл - это скомпилированный (бинарный) файл статической библиотеки. Для того, чтобы проанализировать его состав можно использовать утилиту `DUMPBIN` из состава VisualStudio. Однако стоит понимать, что никакого исходного кода увидеть так не получится.

Answer (score 2):

Lib-файлы не открываются, а подключаются/включаются в проект. А для работы с ними используется соответствующий этому Lib-файлу Header-файл. Включить же в проект можно или в самой IDE в свойствах проекта или непосредственно в файле проекта директивой #pragma comment (lib, "name.lib")

Comment: ...+ обьявленые функции с пометкой `__import` или `extern` без реализации  будут присоеденены из библиотеки к проэкту.